# Insertion into an optimal route – is it still optimal?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I have been pondering this question for a little while and my colleagues seem unsure as well.

The problem involves a vehicle that must visit several waypoints contained in a large road network. The optimal route visits each waypoint in some sequence from the vehicle's starting position S. The ending position does not matter.

Assume there are 5 waypoints and I've used the A* algorithm and by brute force, have found the optimal route to visit all of them from S. The optimal, shortest route is SABCDE. However, I am now told an additional waypoint X needs to be added somewhere along this route and this new route must also be of optimal length. My question is, given SABCDE is optimal, will the optimal solution incorporating X only require a single route to be diverted via X, or X being appended to the end. Will the most optimal route be one of: SXABCDE, SAXBCDE, SABXCDE, SABCXDE, SABCDXE or SABCDEX? Or, is this not guarenteed to be the case, meaning the optimal solution might be SACXDEB?

Comment: Unfortunately, the new optimal route cannot always be the old optimal route with the new point inserted, otherwise you could solve the travelling salesman problem in polynomial time by inserting one point at a time.

Comment: For a concrete example, consider points SABCDE lying clockwise on a circle, with distance SA < SE; then the optimal path is SABCDE. Now insert X between S and E so that SX = XE < SA; now the optimal path is SXEDCBA.

Comment: @Rahul The reference to the traveling salesman problem is a fantastic comment.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. I kind of suspected it seemed to good to be true, but I couldn't think of a counterexample, and I thought perhaps TSP was a different class of problem with the cycle requirement (this I could prove with a counterexample, as it's not too far off the Nearest Neighbour algorithm).

Comment: @Rahul would you mind putting your comments as answer? (so that the question is not unanswered anymore) Thx